# Count files in a directory using batch file by pattern and perform a task

Tags: batch-file

How can I count number of files in a directory and if none are found, go to a label called "END"?  Here's what I've tried:

```
if dir *.dat /b | find /c /v "dat" EQU 0 goto END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f %%a in ('dir /a-d *.dat /b 2^>nul^| find /c "dat" ') do if %%a EQU 0 goto END
```

should fix your problem.

of course

```
if not exist *.dat goto end
```

would be cleaner (but fails if there are `.dat` directories - as noted by M D)

Comment: Nice first one, but cleaner version fails for "*.dat" folders

Answer (score 0):

```
dir /a-d *.dat >nul 2>nul || goto END
```

If the dir command fails to found any file with the indicated pattern, then error level is raised ant the code after `||` is executed